# Is there a conflict between \hspace and tufte-latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tufte

I want to place two `tikzpictures` side by side in a `tufte-handout`. I can do that with `\hspace` in a `standalone` document, and it works fine. But if I put the same pictures in a `tufte-handout` document, I get a line break between them, even if I use `fullwidth`. How do I fix that situation? Or do `\hspace` and `tufte` not work together?

## MWE

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{fullwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}

                \draw [help lines] (0,-1) -- (0,1);
                \draw [help lines] (0,0) -- (5,0);
                \draw [very thick, red](0,0) sin (1,1) cos (2,0) sin (3,-1) cos (4,0) sin (5,1);

            \end{tikzpicture}

            \hspace*{5mm}

            \begin{tikzpicture}

                \draw [help lines] (0,-1) -- (0,1);
                \draw [help lines] (0,0) -- (4,0);
                \draw [very thick, red](0,1) cos (1,0) sin (2,-1) cos (3,0) sin (4,1);

            \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{fullwidth}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There should be no blank line around `\hspace{5mm}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TeX is not free form. A blank line means a paragraph break and an end-of-line becomes a space (not inside a `tikzpicture`, though).

In `standalone`, paragraphs are ignored by default, not in normal documents, but with that code you get *more* than 5mm, because of the spaces introduced by the end-of-lines.

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{fullwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [help lines] (0,-1) -- (0,1);
  \draw [help lines] (0,0) -- (5,0);
  \draw [very thick, red](0,0) sin (1,1) cos (2,0) sin (3,-1) cos (4,0) sin (5,1);
\end{tikzpicture}% <--- no space
% <--- no blank line
\hspace{5mm}% <--- no space
% <--- no blank line
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [help lines] (0,-1) -- (0,1);
  \draw [help lines] (0,0) -- (4,0);
  \draw [very thick, red](0,1) cos (1,0) sin (2,-1) cos (3,0) sin (4,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{fullwidth}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `\hspace{5mm}` is good as well, in this case. The difference is that `\hspace*` doesn't disappear at line breaks.